# SwiftUI multiple TextField causing lags

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am using many TextFields in my SwiftUI Mac OS app. I am a main form, where the user adds data, which is composed of multiple `Stacks`/ `views` which contain `TextFields`/ and `Text()`

I noticed a strange bug, when I am using many TextFields combined in different views, I get some very heavy lags when selecting the TextField. Also when I skip to the next one with `Tab` it takes time.

It is really strange behavior and I am not sure what is causing that. I have a different view with many `TextFields` aswell, where everything is working smooth.

Also sometimes I can not jump back to the prior `TextField` with `Shift+Tab`.

**Edit:** I could figure out how to get rid of it. However, only if I remove one view. I don't want to.

My main container looks like that:

```
    HStack
    {
       //Left Side
       VStack{
           Text("Here is the next #1")
       }
       VStack
       {
           //The View posted below
           ViewBelow()
       }
    }
```

**If I remove the first VStack, the issue is solved. Nothing lagging. If I add it, it is there again.**

Just to give you a neckline of my code (many Stacks with TextFields)

```
 ZStack
 {
    VStack
    {
        HStack
        {
            Text("Personal Data")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding(.horizontal, 0)
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
            Spacer()
        }

        Divider()
            .padding(.bottom, 5)

        //Personal Data Types
        HStack(spacing: 0)
        {
            //Left Element
            VStack(alignment: .center)
            {
                Text("Vorname")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)

            } .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

            //Right Elemenet
            VStack()
            {
                Text("Nachname")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

        }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)

        HStack(spacing: 0)
        {
            VStack(alignment: .center)
            {
                //Left Element
                if (self.editMode)
                {
                    TextField("Enter some text", text: $s_test)
                        .frame(maxWidth:250)
                }
                else
                {
                    Text(self.person.firstName)
                        .font(.body)
                }

            } .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

            VStack()
            {
                //Left Element
                if (self.editMode)
                {
                    TextField("Enter some text", text: self.$s_test)
                        .frame(maxWidth:250)
                }
                else
                {
                    Text(self.person.lastName)
                        .font(.body)
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

        }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.top, 0)


        //Personal Data Types
        HStack(spacing: 0)
        {
            //Left Element
            VStack(alignment: .center)
            {
                Text("Nickname")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)

            } .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

            //Right Elemenet
            VStack()
            {
                Text("Birthday")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

        }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.top, 10)


        HStack(spacing: 0)
        {
            VStack(alignment: .center)
            {
                //Left Element
                if (self.editMode)
                {
                    TextField("Enter some text", text: self.$s_test)
                        .frame(maxWidth:250)
                }
                else
                {
                    Text(self.person.nickname)
                        .font(.body)
                }

            } .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

            VStack()
            {
                //Right Element
                if (self.editMode)
                {
                    TextField("Enter some text", text: self.$s_test)
                        .frame(maxWidth:250)
                }
                else
                {
                    Text(self.person.birthdate)
                        .font(.body)
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

        }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.top, 0)
      }
```

Maybe someone experienced the same already.. I am not quiet sure how to solve it. I removed many views, then it is working better. However I am not sure if it is just the quantity of TextFields or some bug in the other view.

I demonstrate the lag in the Gif. I press instantly when I hover above the TextField. See that lag..

[image]

Comment: I don't observe any issue with Xcode 11.2. Of course I replaced your models with static values, so I assume that the issue is not in `TextField`s themselves, but in how they are filled (ie. in model).

Comment: @Asperi Thanks Asperi. I could figure it further. I have posted my main view. That is including the other one below. I have a HStack with two VStacks. If I remove the first VStack, the issue is sovled. I can not split my HStack. Otherwise the TextFields are lagging again.

Comment: My view I included has a ZStack has highest view. Not sure if there is a problem with. However if I include it alone in my HStack it is working. Only if I make a split in my HStack.

Comment: A good approach to make the views are separate each section in an independent struct, maybe this article could help https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/swiftui-why-to-write-custom-views-for-better-performance-561962f1c268

Comment: Thanks.. appreciate. I will read @Mac3n